# HBase slow data load

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hbase, bigdata

I have a problem with loading big data from mysql database into an HBase small cluster. The cluster configurations are as follow

Machine(1): HDFS/ primary HDFS node/ Yarn resource manager/ yarn node manager/ MapReduce / History server /zookeeper / Region Server/

Machine(2): Yarn Node Manager / Secondary HDFS node/  Master HBasse

Machine(3): Yarn Node Manager /zookeeper / Region Server/

Machine(5): /zookeeper / Region Server/

Each machines parameters are 
62GB RAM 
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 0 @ 2.60GHz CPU

Loading the data is as follow: Java JDBC driver connects to MySQL databse, then the read records are mapped to HBase row then they are inserted to HBase. 
Each single record represent a single java class with about 10 primitive type fields.

THE PROBLEM : loading the data takes too much time to load, where could the problem be ? 
For example : about 10 million records take about 6 hours to load from mysql to HBase, is this normal ?
Can this be improved ? 
What are the possible reasons that could make loading data from mysql using java JDBC driver into HBase that slow ?

Comment: 6 hours is too much time. May be the bottleneck is your program which is converting the mysql row to java class. Try sqoop (http://sqoop.apache.org) to import rows and then compare the time taken.

Comment: Basically I do ready mysql row with simple JDBC driver to map to a simple JAVA class then from this java class I map to HBase row ... and insert !